# How to debug the noscript tag

Tags: javascript, widget, noscript

I am making a widget and I wrapped some JavaScript with a noscript tag and now I just get a blank screen and no error messages I can notice.

Here is the example: http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?hike_id=108&height=600&width=700

If you paste in the url from the view-source of that page, you will get something happening. But for some reason, this url I linked to shows nothing.  Why is that happening?

Thanks!!

Comment: Wrapping some JavaScript in a `<noscript>` tag kind-of doesn't make sense.

Comment: `<noscript>` is for containing stuff you want to show if there's no JS support.

Comment: take the javascript out of the no script tag. i am sure your script will work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a lot *to* debug. Just try the page with JS on and with it off. As usual, [validating](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comehike.com%2Foutdoors%2Fwidget.php%3Fhike_id%3D108%26height%3D600%26width%3D700&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) is helpful.

If you have JavaScript turned on, then the `<noscript>` element will be ignored and you see nothing. This is expected.

If you have JavaScript turned off, then the `<iframe>` will be rendered, and the page inside loaded. That page consists of a heading, a few empty elements, and a lot of JavaScript (which won't run because JS isn't turned on).

Comment: +1 Pretty much exactly what I was saying in my answer, but you got there first. ;)

Comment: @Quentin Ah, so should I add more code to render the widget after the noscript closing tag? Or should I take the iframe code out of the noscript tag?  Any idea how this is meant to work? :)

Comment: To make the link valid, close it with </a> as @Shaz says in his answer.

Comment: @Genadinik — I don't know what it is supposed to do, in what context, so it is hard to say. Why did you use `<noscript>` in the first place? Why did you use an iframe to a script dependent page there?

Comment: @Quentin I used noscript because I was advised it was good practice.  I used iframe because I want to allow people to export this as a widget on their sites. When it renders correctly it shows a hike map with the trailhead, and the actual route of the hike.

Comment: I think that the advice was supposed to be "When writing something heavily dependent on scripting, use `<noscript>` to provide an alternative." That isn't actually very good advice (good advice is [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)), and it doesn't mean "Wrap all your content in `<noscript>`".

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the `<a>` tag.

Before:

```
<noscript>
<iframe style="width:700px;height:600px" src="http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/hike_widget.php?hike_id=108&height=600&width=700" >
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>

    <p><a href="http://www.comehike.com/">Widget by comehike.com</p>
</noscript>
```

After:

```
<noscript>
<iframe style="width:700px;height:600px" src="http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/hike_widget.php?hike_id=108&height=600&width=700" >
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>

    <p><a href="http://www.comehike.com/">Widget by comehike.com</a></p>
</noscript>
```

Remember, anything inside the `<noscript>` tag will only be displayed to browsers that either don't support JavaScript or have it disabled.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript inside a `<noscript>` tag will never be activated - the element will only be rendered if the browser doesn't support the language specified in the `<script>` tags (or it's disabled).

To test the noscript tags, you can use an HTML validator to ensure you've placed the `<noscript>` tags in valid / legal places in your HTML.

http://validator.w3.org/

Other than that, just view your pages with JavaScript disabled to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks - so the iframe stuff should be taken out of the noscript tag, correct?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't wrap the iframe with noscript - I don't see the need and apparently some browsers protect against iframes embedded in noscript tags.